# null=True in model not accepting null values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
reportnotesform=ReportNotes(instance=report)
if request.method == 'POST':
    locationnotesform=LocationNotes(request.POST,instance=report)
    if locationnotesform.is_valid():
        locationnotesform.save()
```

forms.py

```
class LocationNotes(forms.ModelForm):
    other_location = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'ir-textbox'}))
    location_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'style':'width:20em'}))
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    location_description = models.TextField('Location description', null=True, blank=True)
    other_location = models.CharField('Other', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am able to save the data,form is in update mode.

If i delete all data in field and click save,the field is not getting saved,means it is not taking null values.

Saving white space,but null is not saving.I want it to accept null values also.

Comment: Both answers are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is fine but form would be giving you error.
Pass `required=False` to your field definitions in the form.

```
class LocationNotes(forms.ModelForm):
    other_location = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'ir-textbox'}))
    location_description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'style':'width:20em'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand it correctly, In your `LocationNotes` form you need to make `other_location` and `location_description` optional also:

```
other_location = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'ir-textbox'}),
    required=False)
```